# Win - Can you create a hidden folder in one step?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, ntfs

As far as I know, the way to create a hidden folder is:

CreateDirectory( folderName );
SetFileAttributes( folderName, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN );

Doing this causes the directory to exist, for a moment, as not hidden.  Other programs like cloud software and backup can mistakenly see it as non-hidden...  and do something with it.

Is it possible to achieve the same thing in a single API call?  One atomic step?  Seems like it should be possible!  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CreateDirectoryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363856.aspx) for this.

> Creates a new directory with the attributes of a specified template directory. If the underlying file system supports security on files and directories, the function applies a specified security descriptor to the new directory. The new directory retains the other attributes of the specified template directory.

You need a template directory handy with suitable (i.e. hidden) attributes.

Comment: Then, just use CreateDirectoryEx for creating the template directory. No, wait...

Comment: I was joking. I am not funny.

Comment: @manuell Looks like it is me without the sense of humour! ;-)

Comment: This is a possibility for me...  Will have to explore.  It's a workaround for an API that should exist.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe these steps would help you:

1. Create the directory outside the backup/cloud zone,
2. make it hidden,
3. then move it to the desired location.

Answer (score 1):

Create the directory as a temp directory. `GetTempPath()` will give you the path to your temp directory:

```
DWORD WINAPI GetTempPath(
  _In_   DWORD nBufferLength,
  _Out_  LPTSTR lpBuffer
  ) ;
```

Use that to create a unique temp file name with `GetTempFileName()`:

```
UINT WINAPI GetTempFileName(
  _In_   LPCTSTR lpPathName,
  _In_   LPCTSTR lpPrefixString,
  _In_   UINT uUnique,
  _Out_  LPTSTR lpTempFileName
  ) ;
```

That will, depending on how it's invoked, either

- create an empty file with a unique name (uUnique is zero), or
- just return the unique name (uUnique is non-zero).

Then create a directory of that name in the temp directory. When you've got it into the condition you want it WRT attributes (hidden, etc.), then move it into its final location with [`MoveFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`MoveFileEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Of course, it might be easier just to get the temp path as above, and iteratively try to create a subdirectory, generating a unique temp name using a GUID or the current date/time and appending an incrementing suffix. Once the directory is created, then set its attributes and proceed as above to move it to its final location.

Comment: MoveFile/Ex() cannot move directories across volumes, so this would only work if the destination is on the same drive as the temp directory.

Comment: The "temp" idea may be cool with the "template" idea from David Heffernan.

Comment: This is really sort of hacky, in my opinion.  Under the hood it's possible to do this in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CreateDirectoryTransacted()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SetFileAttributesTransacted()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) within a single transaction that is created with [`CreateTransaction()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and committed with [`CommitTransaction()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), eg:

```
HANDLE hTrans = CreateTransaction(...);
CreateDirectoryTransacted(..., hTrans);
SetFileAttributesTransacted(..., hTrans);
CommitTransaction(hTrans);
CloseHandle(hTrans);
```

Comment: Those APIs are deprecated and will be removed as I recall

Comment: Microsoft is not in the habit of removing deprecated APIs, though.

Comment: That's true. And normally I'd take that stance. But they seem more strident about transacted io than many other deprecated APIs.

Comment: I saw these too when I started researching this topic.  Microsoft doesn't really seem to do away with anything deprecated.  And, I don't get why they would want to do this?!?  Should I give into the temptation to use them?

Comment: @Lompican These will be removed, or at least stop working transactionally in my judgement.

Comment: createDirectoryEx might b the better choice.  Any idea why they would get rid of something so useful?

Comment: According to MS, there has been practically no interest from developers and I expect it is expensive and constraining to maintain: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802690(v=vs.85).aspx